# Why won't my autogenerated id value work?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am very new to Symfony 3. I was able to create tables and interact with them. Here is the code that works:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="table")
 */
class table
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

But when I try to add one line of code to get

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
```

and run this (or almost anything) in my terminal:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

then I get these errors:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
>   An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or
>   directory
>   [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                  SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2002] No such file or directory
>                                     [PDOException]                                       SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

and can't deploy my project. What could be causing this?

Comment: If this "isn't a real question," then please give me a chance to improve it before getting me banned from SO.

Comment: Looks like a problem with database connection, check the doctrine database settings and database itself.

Comment: What are your DB setting?

Comment: Which settings, like the database name, user, password, etc?

Comment: Please note that without the GeneratedValue line, I am able to read from the database and edit the database. My app has no problem connecting to the database. I'm just trying to make one of the columns auto generate the id so that I don't have to manually set it.